# How to generate number of spiral arms dynamically?

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics, simulation-nodes

Generate number of arms dynamically.

I'm trying to have the number of "arms" generated by typing in a number.  At the moment I use several switch nodes that already have the number of arms and the angles required (pre-calculated) in a Blender 3.6 file.

[image: ani1]

I'm trying to make this a little more dynamic by using Blender 4.0 and a `Repeat Node` (I shouldn't have to hard code the math along with switch nodes using the Repeat node) but I'm having some issues with the logic and calculations.

The Blender 3.6 hard coded number of arms file is attached below.

[image]

I was trying something like this in Blender 4.0 but the calculations where off.

[image: img1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for a *Repeat* loop here, if you instance primitive *Curve>Spiral* s on another (resampled) primitive *Curve>Circle*:

[image]

this version might provide you with all the adjustment you need.. if not, there's the option to do some maths...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I modified RB's solution to derive *Inner Radius* from *Arm Width*, you could add something to the latter, or multiply it by something, before using it in the calculation, to still have the radius dependent on the arm, but also have some constant/relative spacing between arms. You could also do the calculations in the other way, to derive the *Arm Width* from the *Inner Radius*…

[image]

[image]

[image]